# My navbar switches from horizontal to vertical when the screen width is under a certain size

Tags: css

Apologies in advance if the answer to this is fairly obvious, I've been researching an answer but I'm not sure if my phrasing has been correct.

As these pictures illustrate, whenever I resize my window under a certain size my navbar goes from horizontal to vertical.

these images will show what i mean:

1. as intended... https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdtK0.png
2. not quite. . . https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6UmI.png

HTML:

```java
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <li><a>Blog</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <li><a>Artists</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <li><a>Shop/Listen</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <li><a>About/Contact</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <li><a>Photos/Videos</a></li>
                    </div>

                </ul>
            </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#navbar {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    min-width: 800px;
    float: clear;

}

#navbar ul {

    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 300px;


}

#navbar li {

    margin-left: 10px
    display: block;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    border: solid red 2px;


}

#navbar a {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #68716A;
    font-weight: 200;
    top: 20px;

}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

EDIT: i'm using Bootstrap for the columns

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this: http://jsfiddle.net/tsv76sc6/. You must have some additional code. Are you using any frameworks, external CSS files, or media queries?

Comment: yes i forgot to mention that I'm also using Bootstrap for the columns

Comment: Does it happen with all of the major browsers?  What if you set `overflow-x: scroll;`?  You're also missing a semicolon on `#navbar li { margin-left: 10px`

Comment: happens in Chrome and Safari. just tried adding overflow-x: scroll; and it didn't seem to work unfortunately. (i was hoping there wouldn't be an error like that, yeesh. thanks @adamdc78 :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"col-md-2" class is for medium sized screens. "col-xs-2" would be safer if you want it to work also on small screens.